# Structural Similarity Loss implementation on pytorch gives NaN

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, torchvision, semantic-segmentation

I decided to write my lossfunction Structural Similarity Loss according to the article
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.08711.pdf

Testing different models for segmentation and different losses for them I have a problem that sometimes there is numerical instability and my self-written Segnet model gives out NaN during training, due to which loss also becomes NaN. While on other losses (bce, dice loss, focal loss) everything is stable. After printing out the variables in detail, I found out that the loss value before the y_pred=NaN arrives is adequate, so my assumption is that the loss gradients are counted incorrectly, but it's not clear how to fix it.

```
def ssl_loss (y_real, y_pred, window_size=11, eps = 0.01):
    beta = 0.1
    Lambda = 0.5
    
    #input size(B, C, H, W)
    #C = 1, because we compare monochrome segmentations

    y_real, y_pred = y_real.to(device).squeeze(), y_pred.to(device).squeeze()
    
    bce_matrix = (y_pred - y_real * y_pred + torch.log(1 + torch.exp(-y_pred)))
    
    y_pred = torch.sigmoid(y_pred)
    
    blurer = T.GaussianBlur(kernel_size=(11, 11), sigma=(1.5, 1.5))
    
    mu_y = blurer(y_real)
    sigma_y = blurer((y_real - mu_y) ** 2)
    
    mu_p = blurer(y_pred)
    sigma_p = blurer((y_pred - mu_p) ** 2)
    
    errors = torch.abs((y_real - mu_y + eps) / (torch.sqrt(sigma_y) + eps) - (y_pred - mu_p + eps) / (torch.sqrt(sigma_p) + eps)).squeeze()
    
    f_n_c = (errors > beta * errors.max()).int()
    
    M = f_n_c.sum(dim=(1, 2)).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2)
    
    ssl_matrix = (errors * f_n_c * bce_matrix / M)
    
    loss = Lambda * bce_matrix.mean() + (1 - Lambda) * ssl_matrix.mean()
    
    return loss
```

And here's meaningful part of my train function

```
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        avg_loss = 0
        model.train()
        for X_batch, Y_batch in data_tr:
            X_batch = X_batch.to(device)
            Y_batch = Y_batch.to(device)

            opt.zero_grad()

            Y_pred = model(X_batch)
            
            loss =  loss_fn(Y_batch, Y_pred)
            loss.backward()
            opt.step()
            
            avg_loss += loss / len(data_tr)
        
        scheduler.step()
```

Comment: Have you checked for issues by looking at the intermediate results of your loss function?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, nan comes at some point, but before that, all loss values ​​​​are good.

Comment: The question you need to answer though is *at which point* that is!